# What is the major difference between AWS Elastic Beanstalk & Docker. Which one should i use?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker, node.js, amazon-beanstalk

I just started learning about Amazon elastic beanstalk, and it seems very good and useful. However, it seems like Docker can be used for the same thing.

AWS EB let's you create environments in Node.js, PHP, Java and start an app in few steps very fast. Meanwhile Docker is built for this purpose too, with images readily available to use.

What's the major difference between both. I'm asking because i want to build a Node.js API which will be very robust and capable of handling a lot of traffic. Which is better?

Answer (score 3):

Elastic Beanstalk is basically a wrapper around other AWS services and helps you to deploy the code to AWS without knowing much about the infrastructure. In the background it still uses services like EC2 instances and LoadBalancers. You can put together similar type of automation with CloudFormation and CodeDeploy.

Docker is a container solution. It helps you to package the application, but a docker container does not provide any infrastructure on its own. You can deploy Docker containers to various environments. It can be AWS ECS cluster or Kubernetes cluster or you can now deploy Docker container with Elastic Beanstalk.

So each of these two things focus on little bit different problems (even though related ones).